# How to use openjdk-8-native as default java in yocto build?

Tags: java, yocto, openembedded

Within one of my application logic recipes, I need to use `java` during compilation time on the host system. The tool needs java 1.8 and fails to work with the `jamvm-native` and `cacao-native` packages.

What I have tried so far is to add the `meta-java` layer to my configuration and add `DEPENDS = openjdk-8-native` to my application logic recipe. This makes yocto compile the openjdk-8-native just fine.

Then, when I start a `devshell` for my own recipe `java -version` gives me

```
java version "1.5.0"
JamVM version 2.0.0
```

I can find the correct `java` from `openjdk-8-native` within the `recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-8-native/bin/` directory, but how can I make it the default `java` in PATH or use `update-alternatives` to make my build tool pick it up correctly?

Just for clarification: I do *not* need java on the target, just a native build during build time of another tool. I'm currently using yocto rocko version.

Comment: I'm not using java at all, but standard `PREFERRED_PROVIDER_x` and `PREFERRED_VERSION_x` in configuration don't help?

Comment: Unfortunately, `PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/java-native` only allows `jamvm-native` or `cacao-native`. I managed to get my stuff working by using `export PATH="${STAGING_LIBDIR_NATIVE}/jvm/openjdk-8-native/bin:$PATH"`, but that seems hacky to me. So the question still holds: Is there an official way to have /usr/bin/java point to openjdk-8-native?

Comment: Just saw a fresh email regarding openjdk-8-native and its support in OE and other layers. Maybe you will find something there: http://lists.openembedded.org/pipermail/openembedded-devel/2019-February/198299.html

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Have you already got a solution?